# $scope.$watch doesn't work as expected

Tags: angularjs

Now, I am using a check box to disable/undisable other buttons's click.
My code is here:

```
<button  class="dateicon" ng-disabled='ExpReport.Beld' ng-click="openstart($event)">button1</button>  
<button  ng-disabled='ExpReport.Beld' class="dateicon" ng-click="openend($event)">button2</button>
<input id='beld' ng-model='ExpReport.Beld' class='checkboxinline' type='checkbox'/>

$scope.ExpReport.Beld = false;
$scope.$watch('ExpReport.Beld',function(){
            if($scope.ExpReport.Beld=true){
           $scope.ExpReport.startdate = '';
           $scope.ExpReport.enddate = '';
          }
        })
```

it seems like the checkbox is always set false, when I make a breakpoint, it will set true,then turn back to false immediately. any idea?

Comment: put a Plunker or JSBin but your issue is the comparison sign, ```$scope.ExpReport.Beld === true```, instead of ```$scope.ExpReport.Beld=true```

Comment: `$scope.ExpReport.Beld === true` is probably redundant; just use `$scope.ExpReport.Beld`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line

```
if($scope.ExpReport.Beld=true){
```

is actually assignment of the $scope.ExpReport.Beld variable, not a comparison. Make sure you use double or triple equals.

```
if($scope.ExpReport.Beld == true){
```

or

```
if($scope.ExpReport.Beld){
```

will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($scope.ExpReport.Beld=true){
```

this line. If you are doing a comparison, use == or ===